# Skip multiple rules during SQL Server installation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, linux, installation

I want to install SQL Server 2008, but I get 2 errors which prevent me from going forward.  I know from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476719/how-do-i-fix-a-performance-counter-registry-hive-consistency-when-installing-s/32583309#32583309) how to skip one rule. Is there a method to skip both?

I am using Wine (PayOnLinux) on Linux and simulated an environment with help of [this post](http://mynixworld.info/2012/12/22/ms-sql-server-on-linux-yes-it-works/). I managed to skip first rule, but I also need to skip the PowerShell rule. I am just interested to know if the below syntax can be altered to skip 2 rules:

```
setup.exe /ACTION=install /SKIPRULES=PerfMonCounterNotCorruptedCheck
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, just separate the rules with a space, for example:

```
/SkipRules=PerfMonCounterNotCorruptedCheck FacetPowerShellCheck
```

While SkipRules is undocumented, the list of rules is documented at:

- [Edition Upgrade Rules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645998(v=sql.100).aspx)

Even more information at:

- [SQL 2012 Setup Rules – The 'Missing Reference'](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/arvindsh/archive/2014/04/02/sql-setup-rules-reference.aspx)